# Where are lists stored in Rightfont?

Tags: fonts

I use Rightfont as my font manager.  I made a bunch of lists and I need to migrate them to a new user profile on the same computer.  Is there a way to copy the lists to the new user without recreating the list and dragging each font manually?  The new profile also shares the same Fonts as the original user.

Comment: This is not a question about graphic design, check the [help] on how to ask a good question and what topics are accepted. Perhaps you should ask it on superuser.com

Comment: It might not be a question about design but it's a great question! I've had to re-install my system and can't re-import my font lists. I still have my old system, have emailed RightFont twice and tweeted them but no joy. Did you find a solution?